# My Countdown App from Date Picker in Android Studio resets to zero when I close it

Tags: java, android

This is the layout.xml file which displays my selected time. The app resets when I close it which beats the whole point of making a countdown app.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <cn.iwgang.countdownview.CountdownView
            android:id="@+id/countdownView"
            style="@style/CustomFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lottieImage"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-64dp"
            app:isHideTimeBackground="false"
            app:isShowDay="true"
            app:isShowHour="true"
            app:isShowMillisecond="true"
            app:isShowMinute="true"
            app:isShowSecond="true"
            app:isTimeTextBold="true"
            app:suffixDay="d"
            app:suffixGravity="bottom"
            app:suffixHour="h"
            app:suffixMillisecond="ms"
            app:suffixMinute="m"
            app:suffixSecond="s"
            app:suffixTextColor="#000000"
            app:suffixTextSize="12sp"
            app:timeBgColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:timeBgRadius="4dp"
            app:timeTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:timeTextSize="32sp" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTop"
            style="@style/CustomFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/countdownView"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:text="Countdown to New Year"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
            style="@style/CustomFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewTop"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="DatePicker" />
    
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:text="Date Picker"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the datePickerFragment java class

```
    package com.example.mycountdownnewyear;
    
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
    
    import java.util.Calendar;
    
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)
            getActivity(), year, month, day);
        }
    }
```

This is the main activity file, every time I select the date from fragment it works fine , and It     even works in the background but when I close the app then it resets to zero, which beats the whole point of having a countdown app for a date.

```
        package com.example.mycountdownnewyear;
        
        import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.DatePicker;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
        
        import java.text.DateFormat;
        
        import java.util.Calendar;
        import java.util.Date;
        
        import cn.iwgang.countdownview.CountdownView;
        
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
                Button btnDatePicker = findViewById(R.id.btnDatePicker);
        
                btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                        datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
                    }
                });
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        
                String pickerDateString = 
                DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());
                TextView tvDatePicker = findViewById(R.id.textViewContent);
                CountdownView myCountdownView = findViewById(R.id.countdownView);
        
                try {
                    tvDatePicker.setText(pickerDateString);
                    Date now = new Date();
        
                    long currentDate = now.getTime();
                    long pickerDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    long countDownToPickerDate = pickerDate - currentDate;
                    myCountdownView.start(countDownToPickerDate);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the counting algorithm located?

Comment: In the main activity the bottom code

Comment: I'm not sure what the countdown view does but after closing the app, all active tasks of the app will exit, except you start a foreground service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.

Comment: The countdown view displays the countdown to the date we pick in DatePickerDialog, I had an Idea to use service but I don't know how to apply it to the code, please help me.